# how to acces member? MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have class A included into B witch included into C.

In class A I have an ExamItemStates function.
and I can access it from class B:
The ExamItemStates function declared as Public:

```
BOOL ExamItemStates(int nItem, DWORD dwStates) const;
```

Header of B class:

```
class B : public CDialogEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(B)
public:
    B(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    enum { IDD = IDD_B };
    CReportCtrl m_wndList;
protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
//B.cpp
    void B::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
    {
        DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_wndList);
        CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    }
    BOOL B::OnInitDialog()
    {
        CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

        if (m_wndList.ExamItemStates(2, RC_ITEM_CHECKED))
            AfxMessageBox(L"Please write correct name!");
        UpdateData(FALSE);

        return TRUE;
    }
```

I need access it from class C. How I can do that?

Comment: Guys can anyone explain instead off down voting?

Comment: This is very basic C++. Your C++ book will cover class hierarchies, access modifiers and virtual members. Hint: You access `B`'s members from `C` in the same way you access `CDialogEx`' members from `B`. You implemented the latter already. You are essentially asking: How do I solve the problem I already solved? This might explain the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `protected` instead of `private`, methods should generally be `public:`:
for example

```
class Foo
{
protected:
    int a, b;
public:
    void Method1();
};
```

Provide your header file (the one with classes) to get more explanation.

---

That is a typical scheme of a derivable class:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    // elements that cannot be inherited (you cannot use them in the child classes) and cannot be accessed from outside of the class
protected:
    // elements that can be inherited, but cannot be accessed from outside of the class
public:
    // elements that can be inherited and accessed outside the class
};
```

---

example code:

```
class A
{
protected:
    void DerivableMethod();
private:
    int AccessibleOnlyInClassA;
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    void AnotherProtectedMethod();
private:
    int AccessibleOnlyInClassB;
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    void MethodInClasC()
    {
        DerivableMethod();
    }
};
```

Comment: I managed my question. pleas don't down vote my question its important. so I don't know how to find issue. can u help me?

Comment: @Klasik I cannot comment on your question, so I do here - provide the code for all the classes - most important the class A. It is there where you need to set things to be protected.

Comment: ok as I understand I must set ExamItemStates as protected in class A. so how in class C must looks like code and what with data exchange... there is problem for me because I cant declare data exchange in two classes same. can u write some example code I think I will understand then better.

Comment: Dzienkje ;) I will try solve it tomorrow. because today my brain not working.